# Is this a grass or weed?

Tags: identification, grass, weeds

[image]

Located in north central Texas. And what kind of plant is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [poa annua](http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/archives/parsons/turf/publications/weed16.html) or annual bluegrass based on it's lighter color and production of seedheads at such a low height for grass.

It's a grass that's considered a weed when growing in lawns of other varieties. It produces a lot of seeds that will germinate in the following spring and fall but it dies back in the summer. It's a difficult weed to control.

Answer (score 3):

If its growing in your grassed or lawned area, its both, if the definition of weed is a plant growing in the wrong place - its a grass and probably a 'weed' grass because its rate of growth is faster than the grass around it. As to exactly which grass it is, not sure.

Comment: Good definition of weeds, although in the US, at least, one might distinguish between normal weeds (your supplied definition), and plants that are legally considered noxious weeds in the applicable state. In that case, there's a specific list of weeds and you're probably not supposed to grow them whether you like them or not. Children in my junior high or high school used to learn many of Idaho's noxious weeds in a certain agriculture class that I took.